# Microsoft Teams Windows client quits immediately after load

Tags: windows, chromium, microsoft-teams

Recently the Microsoft Teams standalone Windows client started failing to load from shortcuts or directly from an admin command prompt.  No UI appears, the process starts for a second then quits.

AFAIK Teams is an Electron Chromium based apps, supported by the fact that Chrome cmdline params work to some extent:
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Executing:

```
Teams.exe --enable-logging
```

Returns:

```
[13780:0618/153200.398:ERROR:process_singleton_win.cc(300)] Lock file can not be created! Error code: 5
[4700:0618/153200.840:ERROR:broker_win.cc(57)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)
```

From researching I believe the second error is caused by the first one.  And looking at Electron src here:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/32352ad08ee673a4d43e8593ce988b224f6482d3/chrome/browser/process_singleton_win.cc

and since Error code 5 appears to be a permission issue, I think Teams thinks there's already another instance open because it can't write to the lockfile so it exits immediately.

From using Process Monitor to track what Teams.exe is doing I found this:

```
12:34:12.2986796 PM","Teams.exe","4708","CreateFile","C:\Users\gemof\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\lockfile","ACCESS DENIED","Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes, Delete, Disposition: OverwriteIf, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Delete On Close, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: 0"
```

But I've double checked the permissions on that folder and my local account is admin and has full control.  Also tried running Teams.exe as Admin, no luck.  The folder where it tries to create lockfile remains empty.

PS: Tried un/reinstalling Teams, deleting any folder/reg keys associated with Teams as well.

Anyone know how to further debug Chromium/Electron Lockfile issues?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the lock file?  Typically, a lock file should only exist, if an actual instance is running.

Comment: So no lockfile ever gets created by Teams, but weirdly if I manually create one, Teams will load to the Login screen then crash with a bunch of other errors.  It then deletes lockfile and then fails to load again.

Comment: There's often files hanging around in the %appdata% folders under user profile in either local or roaming, I can't write remember. Try cleaning that out as well.

Comment: Yup cleared all traces of Teams out from %appdata% local and roaming.  Also did a fresh install of Chrome.  Used RevoUninstaller.